# Set the currency of the records to be fetched using SOQL

Tags: visualforce, multi-currency, currency, conversion

I have a situation in a multi currency org. 
I have Booking Object as child related to Opportunity Object. On a Visualforce page I want to show list of Bookings related to the a Opportunity.

Problem : Booking object has a Amount field which can be of any currency. My requirement is, irrespective of Booking record's currency I want to show all the bookings according to the currency of Opportunity(Parent) on a page.

I have tried the `convertCurrency(field)` function but it is converting according to user's currency which is not suitable for my requirement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you add some code or query you had so far?

Comment: ``Select Id, Name, Opportunity__r.Amount, Opportunity__r.Id,  
 Opportunity__r.CurrencyIsoCode, Amount__c from BookingObject__c
WHERE  Opportunity__r.CurrencyIsoCode != 'USD'``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, SOQL convertCurrency() [converts to the users currency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_currency_fields.htm), not some arbitrary currency (in your case, the parent Opportunity's currency).

To do this is going to require a VF controller that exploits either the `DatedConversionRate` SObject, if using Advanced Currency Management or the `CurrencyType` SObject if not.

As conversion rates are defined against the org currency, and Opportunity currency is not necessarily org currency, you will have to do two operations:

- Convert Booking amount to Org currency and then ..
- Divide the result by the Opportunity currency-to-Org currency rate

If using `DatedConversionRate`; choose Opportunity.ClsoeDate as the date to use to look up the proper rate.